# Twilio Studio > Function > Voicemail Issue

Tags: twilio

We are currently using Twilio Studio to accept incoming calls. These calls are then handed off to a function, which is a modified version of https://github.com/philnash/useful-twilio-functions/tree/master/hunt, which attempts to reach the agent on their cellphone using whisper (which Studio doesn't support natively). This is the main function:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const numbers = context.AGENT1_NUMBERS.split(',').map(number => number.trim());
  const response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (event.DialCallStatus === 'complete') {
    // Call was answered and completed
    response.hangup();
  } else if (event.finished === 'true') {
    if (context.AGENT1_FINAL_URL) {
      response.redirect(context.AGENT1_FINAL_URL);
    } else {
      response.hangup();
    }
  } else {
    const numberToDial = event.nextNumber ? event.nextNumber : numbers[0];
    const currentNumberIndex = numbers.indexOf(numberToDial);
    let url;
    if (currentNumberIndex + 1 === numbers.length) {
      // No more numbers to call after this.
      url = 'https://redacted.twil.io/agent1?finished=true';
    } else {
      const nextNumber = numbers[currentNumberIndex + 1];
      url = 'https://redacted.twil.io/agent1?nextNumber=' + encodeURIComponent(nextNumber);
    }
    const dial = response.dial({ action: url });
    dial.number({ url: 'https://URL_TO_WHISPER_TWIML' }, numberToDial);
  }
  callback(null, response);
};
```

This is the TwiML Bin for whisper.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="URL_TO_FUNCTION" numDigits="1">
   <Say>You are receiving a call, please dial 1 to accept or anything else to reject</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

This is the next function which connects the call.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (event.Digits === '1') {
    response.say('Connecting');
  } else {
    response.hangup();
  }
  callback(null, response);
}
```

Now, the issue here is that the AGENT1_FINAL_URL points to a TwiML bin that handles voicemail. This process occurs just fine if the call is answered by the agent and disconnected without pressing 1. The caller is sent to the Twilio voicemail. If, however, the agent just misses the call or rejects the call, the call continues to ring on the caller's end until I suspect it's times out, after which the caller is connected anyway and will hear a cut off version of the agents personal voicemail on their cellphone. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `timeout` attribute to the `<Dial>` in this line: `dial = response.dial({ action: url });`? The `<Dial>` shouldn't connect anyway, it should call the `action` URL. I'm concerned about how this is interacting with Studio too, are there other widgets this call goes through before calling out to this function?

Comment: I added a timeout as that was Twilios suggestion. It helped address the issue of letting the call ring out, but if the call is rejected or goes directly to voicemail, it's considered answered and the call is connected. This is what Twilio said:

"If the call to the agent goes to voicemail and then completes its not passed back to your script and thus cannot go on to the TwiML voicemail."

And:

"Whisper is intended for the purpose of having something said or media played to only one participant so the other participant cant hear what is said/played."

Comment: Those comments from Twilio aren't super helpful it seems. If the whisper meets the voicemail, then the `<Gather>` should time out and make the request to the `action` URL without any `Digits` pressed so the call should hangup. Are you seeing that happen at all?

Comment: No. If the agent answers and disconnects without pressing 1, it works. After adding timeout and making that 15 seconds, letting the call ring without answer or rejecting it works. Reject the call and the caller is connected anyway. I haven't tried answering and not pressing 1, that might be interesting. I think I tried bypassing Studio entirely, but I'll try that when I'm back from vacation this weekend.

Comment: If you reject the call, does the webhook to the whisper still fire? And can you read the call status from the parameters sent to it?